# Issue with makefile on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to install a program that consist of a folder with some C files. I run the makefile but i get the following error:

```
/home/silviu/Desktop/tipsy-2.2.3d/code/readline/display.c:1128: undefined reference to `tgoto'
/home/silviu/Desktop/tipsy-2.2.3d/code/readline/display.c:1129: undefined reference to `tputs'
/home/silviu/Desktop/tipsy-2.2.3d/code/readline/display.c:1138: undefined reference to `tputs'
/home/silviu/Desktop/tipsy-2.2.3d/code/readline/display.c:1145: undefined reference to `tputs'
/home/silviu/Desktop/tipsy-2.2.3d/code/readline/display.c:1154: undefined reference to `tputs'
readline/libreadline.a(display.o): In function `delete_chars':
/home/silviu/Desktop/tipsy-2.2.3d/code/readline/display.c:1182: undefined reference to `tgoto'
/home/silviu/Desktop/tipsy-2.2.3d/code/readline/display.c:1183: undefined reference to `tputs'
/home/silviu/Desktop/tipsy-2.2.3d/code/readline/display.c:1189: undefined reference to `tputs'
readline/libreadline.a(signals.o): In function `cr':
/home/silviu/Desktop/tipsy-2.2.3d/code/readline/signals.c:301: undefined reference to `tputs'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do you know how can I solve it? (on Ubuntu)

Comment: Do you have `curses` library installed? Does the program contain `configure` script?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I used ./configure in order to obtain the makefile. How can I install the curses library?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev`. And read the documentation (if any) for your program for other dependencies.

Comment: You should link some libraries. Compile with these parameters `-ltermcap -lncurses`.

Comment: Well, if it passed `configure`, the required libs should be ok.. Unless it warned you about it.

Comment: @SergeySalnikov I run it but it tell me libncurses5-dev is already the newest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `tputs` in c program so you must have use `#include <curses.h>` and `#include <term.h>`. Undefined reference is *linker error*. In Makefile while compiling c program you should link `-lcurses` or `-lncurses`. Add similar line to your Makefile. compile with appropriate linking library.

For example

```
gcc file.c -o output_file -lcurses -ltermcap
```

or

```
gcc file.c -o output_file -lcurses -ltermcap
```

Comment: I had to add `-ltermcap` in addition to `-lncurses` to solve tputs reference.